# Helm chart incorrectly array render

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I did not figured out how to proper render nested template array of objects

values.yaml

```yaml
persistence:
  volumes:
    - name: api-manutencao-env2
      configMap:
        name: api-manutencao-env2
    - name: api-manutencao-env2
      configMap:
        name: api-manutencao-env2
```

deployment.yaml (template)

```yaml
      {{- if .Values.persistence }}
      volumes:
      {{- range .Values.persistence.volumes }}
      {{ . | toYaml | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

Result:

```yaml
      volumes:
      
        configMap:
          name: api-manutencao-env2
        name: api-manutencao-env2
      
        configMap:
          name: api-manutencao-env2
        name: api-manutencao-env2
---
```

I render its content reversed and break in the array structure not being add the - and the correct ident.

I've tried https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Helm_Template_range and it did not work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to call `toYaml` on the entire list, rather than iterating through it on your own.

```yaml
{{- with .Values.persistence }}
      volumes:
{{ toYaml .volumes | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
```

If you iterate through the list with `range`, and you want the YAML list markers, you need to emit them yourself.

```yaml
{{- with .Values.persistence }}
      volumes:
{{- range .volumes }}
        - {{ toYaml . | indent 10 | trim }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

`indent` puts spaces in front of every line including the first one, so in this construct you need to `trim` leading and trailing whitespace, causing the first line of the rendered output to appear immediately after the hyphen.

The order of items in a YAML mapping isn't important, and at the underlying Go `map[string]interface{}` layer it isn't preserved.  In the [Go `text/template` language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `range` is documented as iterating over maps in sorted key order.  Helm's `toYaml` extension isn't especially well-documented; [`toJson`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) at least appears in the documentation but it doesn't say anything about key order.  It doesn't matter whether `name:` or `configMap:` comes first and Helm won't remember the ordering from `values.yaml`; there's nothing you can do to control this.